# Bluetooth OnReceive Method Doesn't Get Called

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make an android app which has some issues about Bluetooth. I simply enable Bluetooth, find devices, connect one of the devices, send & receive data. First thing is done. But in second, there are some problems. I make a `Broadcast Receiver` to discover devices nearby my phone. But `OnReceive` method doesn't get called. The weird thing is, it was getting called at first and I was able to see devices nearby. Then something that I cannot figure out happened and now `OnReceive` method doesn't get called. I've searched topics about these but none of them could solve my problem. `MyDevice` and `MyAdapter` are my own classes to show Bluetooth devices in listview with my own layout. Here is my code:

```
public class FoundDevicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
ListView foundedDevicesListView;
MyDeviceAdapter deviceAdapter;
List<MyDevice> foundedDevicesList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_found_devices);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    foundedDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.foundDevicesListview);

    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

    this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    deviceAdapter = new MyDeviceAdapter(this, foundedDevicesList);
    foundedDevicesListView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(FoundDevicesActivity.this, "Discovery is started !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Found Devices Activity", "Discovery is started !!");
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            MyDevice dvc = new MyDevice();
            if (device.getName().equals(null)) {
                dvc.name = "UNDEFINED NAME";
            } else {
                dvc.name = device.getName();
            }

            if(device.getAddress().equals(null)) {
                dvc.address = "UNDEFINED ADDRESS";
            } else {
                dvc.address = device.getAddress();
            }
            foundedDevicesList.add(dvc);
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(FoundDevicesActivity.this, "Discovery is finished !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Found Devices Activity", "Discovery is finished !!");
        }
    }
};
```

}

Any idea ?

Comment: turn on your phone gps

Comment: It is already opened